# Complex argument function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

How is $arg(x+yi)$ defined such that $x>0$? I've seen some equal to $arctan$ and others equal to $arccos$ so now I'm baffled

Comment: "Defined such that $\;x>0\;$"? I don't think there is such a thing. Perhaps you meant "defined *for* $\;x>0\;$ ?

Comment: This is $\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ for $x>0$.

Comment: The easiest way to understand this definition is to draw a picture of the right triangle defined by the real/imaginary axes and $x+iy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is defined however you need it defined.

It is not defined in terms of $\arctan$ or $\arccos$. Those are just formulas expressing it, not the definition. The definition is that $\arg(x + iy)$ is the angle $\theta$ such that $$x + iy = r\cos \theta + ir\sin\theta,$$ where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

The thing to note about that definition, though, is that $\theta$ is not fully determined by it. $\theta + 2k\pi$ for any integer $k$ has the same property. This is what I meant about it being defined however you need it defined. Based on the needs of the particular problem you are working on, you can choose to demand that $-\frac\pi 2 < \theta < \frac\pi 2$ or $\frac{3\pi} 2 < \theta < \frac{5\pi} 2$ or whatever other range covering $x > 0$ is most useful. All of the choices are represented by "$\arg(x + iy)$" with the actual range determined by context.

Since the definition provides $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, you can take the ratio to get $$\frac yx = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \tan \theta$$ and thus $$\theta = \arctan\frac yx$$ Or you can solve $x = r\cos\theta$ and make use of the definition of $r$ above:
$$\theta = \arccos\frac xr = \arccos \frac x{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$
or do the same for $y = r\sin\theta$:
$$\theta = \arcsin\frac yr = \arcsin \frac y{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$

But note that these are $\operatorname{arc}$, not $\operatorname{Arc}$, functions. That is, the output is whatever range is appropriate for your problem, not necessarily the principle ranges represented by the $\operatorname{Arc}$ prefix.